# TypeError: string.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm solving an exercise problem. Solved it in Visual Studio (it worked), copied the solution to the browser (Codewars challenge) and it returned this error:

```
TypeError: string.split is not a function
   at bulk
    at _
    at begin
    at it
        at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:159:11
    at Promise._execute
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    at new Promise
    at Object.describe
            at Object.handleError
        at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext
```

Here's my code:

```js
function bulk(string) {
    var arr = string.split(", ");
    var whatYouAte = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/g /g, ' ');
        whatYouAte.push(arr[i].split(" "));
    }

    var proteins = 0; 
    var calories = 0; 

    console.log(whatYouAte);

    for (var j = 0; j < whatYouAte.length; j++) {
        var foodAmount = whatYouAte[j][0];
        var foodName = whatYouAte[j][1];
        var foodProteinKcal = food[foodName][0];
        var foodCarbKcal = food[foodName][1];
        var foodFatKcal = food[foodName][2];
        proteins += foodAmount / 100 * foodProteinKcal;
        calories += foodAmount / 100 * (foodProteinKcal + foodCarbKcal + foodFatKcal); 

    }

    return "Total proteins: " + proteins + " grams, Total calories: " + calories + ".";
}
```

I think I once had a similar problem and solved it by making this.split(), but now this doesn't work (Codewars doesn't accept, returns "TypeError: this.split is not a function"). 
Thanks!

Comment: Most probable cause is that your variable `string` isn't a String

Comment: Where is `food` declared? How are you calling `bulk`?

Comment: @Scott: Food is an object declared within Codewars and used when testing the solution; I can't see it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting a number you can use the `.toString()` method.

I'm using something like this:

```
if (typeof string === 'number') {
    string = num.toString();
}
```

First, use the `typeof` operator to check if it's a number.
Then use the `.toString` method to change it to a string. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great first answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you call `.split()` on something other than a string, the JS runtime won't find the `.split()` method for that type. Make sure you are passing a string to your function.

Here's an example:

```js
var result = "Scott Marcus".split(" "); 

console.log(result); // ["Scott", "Marcus"]

var value = 42
value.split("4");  // ERROR: split is not a function
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My bad, I realized just now that it is indeed an array, e.g. ['300g turkey, 300g potatoes, 100g cucumber']. So I changed the first two lines of code to read: function bulk(arr) { var arr = arr[0].split(", ");  (etc) but this again gives an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
   at bulk

Comment: @PerryPrunesquallor Now the error indicates that `arr[0]` is undefined, not that `split` is not a function. This indicates that your input `arr` is still not what you think it is. This error indicates that the function is being called without any input at all.

Comment: @ScottMarkus, that's true, I mistakenly tested for a string in VB instead of an array and that's why it worked in VB and not on Codewars... I'm blind, what can I say